# WPF adding new row to filled datatable from DB

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, xaml

So i'm working on a school project using wpf .net framework.

I have a DB that has column : id, name, date, startTime, endTime, host.

And in my software i want to add these values in a Datatable. that worked using MysqlDataAdapter and filling the dataTable.

but now after all these values are added i want to programmaticly add a new Column named TotalTime, the row values of this column is (endTime - startTime) * 60 to calculate totalTime in minutes.

I think its redundant to add this column in the DB so that's why i added it by code.

But the issue i'm facing is when i filled the datatable en try to add the NewRow to the column, the rows will add it in a new row instead of add it in the first row of the filled data.

How can i add the NewRow to this datagrid on line 1 instead of creating new empty rows like the images.

Thank you in advance!

[image: See image of datagrid issue]

The code for filling the datatable:

```
public void GetProgrammaOverzicht(int zenderId)
    {
        try
        {
            Programmas.programmaDataTable.Clear();
            var query = $"SELECT naam, datum, begin_tijd, eind_tijd, presentator FROM programmas WHERE zenderId={zenderId}";

            ConnectionVariables.conn.Open();

            using (MySqlCommand cmdSel = new MySqlCommand(query, ConnectionVariables.conn))
            {
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdSel);
                da.Fill(Programmas.programmaDataTable);
            }
            ConnectionVariables.conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

And the code where i add the new row + calculate getting the data from DB

```
public void CalculateTotalTime(int zenderId)
        {
            try
            {
                Programmas.beginTijd.Clear();
                Programmas.eindTijd.Clear();
            var query = $"SELECT begin_tijd, eind_tijd FROM programmas WHERE zenderId={zenderId}";

            var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, ConnectionVariables.conn);
            ConnectionVariables.conn.Open();
            var queryresult = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (queryresult.HasRows)
            {
                while (queryresult.Read())
                {
                    Programmas.beginTijd.Add(queryresult.GetString(0));
                    Programmas.eindTijd.Add(queryresult.GetString(1));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Kan duur in minuten niet berekenen");
            }
            queryresult.Close();
            ConnectionVariables.conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ConnectionVariables.conn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

private void OpenProgrammaOverzichtBtn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int currentZenderId;
        string currentZender;
        currentZender = this.Name.Remove(0, 6);
        currentZenderId = Int32.Parse(currentZender);

        ProgrammaOverzichtDialog.IsOpen = true;
        zenderClass.GetProgrammaOverzicht(currentZenderId);
        zenderClass.CalculateTotalTime(currentZenderId);
        if (Programmas.programmaDataTable.Columns.Contains("Duur in minuten"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Column duur in minuten bestaat al");
        }
        else
        {
            DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
            column.ColumnName = "Duur in minuten";
            Programmas.programmaDataTable.Columns.Add(column);
        }
        DataRow row;
        for (int i = 0; i < Programmas.beginTijd.Count; i++)
        {
            string eind = Programmas.eindTijd[i];
            int eindTijd = int.Parse(eind.Remove(2, 3));
            string begin = Programmas.beginTijd[i];
            int beginTijd = int.Parse(begin.Remove(2, 3));
            int totaal = (eindTijd - beginTijd) * 60;
            row = Programmas.programmaDataTable.NewRow();
            row["Duur in minuten"] = totaal;
            Programmas.programmaDataTable.Rows.InsertAt(row, i);
        }
        programmaOverzichtGrid.DataContext = Programmas.programmaDataTable;
    }
}
```

And the xaml where the button is located to open the DATAGRID

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost Name="ProgrammaOverzichtDialog" Background="#FF3F3F46">
                    <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent >
                        <StackPanel>
                            <DataGrid x:Name="programmaOverzichtGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Button FontSize="20px" Foreground="White" Content="programmaoverzicht" Click="OpenProgrammaOverzichtBtn" x:Name="programmaOverzichtBtn"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke a fellow programmer i know gave me a option to try and it worked!

Answer:
In my method "OpenProgrammaOverzichtBtn" i needed to change from

```
        row = Programmas.programmaDataTable.NewRow();
        row["Duur in minuten"] = totaal;
        Programmas.programmaDataTable.Rows.InsertAt(row, i);
```

To:

```
        row = Programmas.programmaDataTable.Rows[i];
        row["Duur in minuten"] = totaal;
        //Programmas.programmaDataTable.Rows.InsertAt(row, i);
```